# Reduce space between two sets of subfloats

Tags: subfloats

I'm using subfloats to fit many pictures in a page. But when I try to use two sets of pictures, the space between them is huge and won't fit the page with a \section.

```
\section{Mudando a função de ativação da camada HL}

\FloatBarrier

\begin{figure}

\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=1pt,captionskip=1pt}

\centering

\subfloat[RMSE e MAPE]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{cfg2_erropurelin.png}}\\

\subfloat[Gráficos]{\includegraphics[width = 5in]{cfg2_plotpurelin.png}}

\caption{Resultados com HL sendo "logsig" e saída "purelin"}

\label{some example}

\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier

\FloatBarrier

\begin{figure}

\centering

\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,captionskip=0pt}

\subfloat[RMSE e MAPE]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{cfg3_errotansigpurelin.png}}\\

\subfloat[Gráficos]{\includegraphics[width = 5in]{cfg3_plottansigpurelin.png}}

\caption{Resultados com HL sendo "tansig" e saída "purelin")}

\label{some example}

\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier
```

[image: huge space between them(the \section is in another page because of that tho)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding the `\raggedbottom` directive in your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`).

Comment: Instead of float barriers, why not just use `\begin{figure}[p]`?

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX and I got used to it because it helped to keep paragraphs in the right places instead of being moved by the pictures. I tried using [p] but it didn't fix the huge gap between the pictures :(

Comment: Tried \raggedbottom but I still got the huge spaces. Thanks anyway!